# Call C#(codebehind) with Ajax in AX 2012 Enterprise portal

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r3, webusercontrols

It seems like the only possible way to call a method in codebehind is with Ajax. Ajax calling WebMethods or ajax calling an asp webservice (asmx).

The problem is that I'm working with Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 Enterprise Portal and creating WebMethods is not possible since I don't have access to the code behind file of the web page. AX 2012 Enterprise portal uses user controls(.ascx files) only.

I've been trying to use asp:UpdatePanels, but that doesn't really work as I want to.

What I want to accomplish is to have a textbox where the user can type something and after 2 or 3 characters, a dropdown should appear right below the textbox with some results.

I've manage to create all of this, but i'm facing with the problem of calling server side code inside of an user controls.

Is web service the only possible way for me or does anyone have a sneaky trick to accomplish this?